# Transfer obeject type (class)

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf

Can SOAP transfer type information with objects? If yes: I use Apache CXF to generate client-side code. Is there a way to make it hint the classes?

Background: I would like to use more general containers like `List<SomeInterface>` (the serverside is Java and NetBeans) in my web service, but without type information the objects could not be restored on server side (or at least I think it would be impossible).